# How to get users current geolocation (country name) in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, geolocation, ip

Its important that operation needed to be realised only thru free services (f.e. https://freegeoip.net). The purpose is to get variable only with country name.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this example my help you:

```
https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/geolocation-php-api/blob/master/examples/example.php
```